# Securing iPads and laptops in an enterprise

Tags: mobile, ios

We have users in our organization who own iPads and we'd like to connect them to the network; however, if the users download and store sensitive data on the devices, that can pose a security issue. Is it possible to prevent users from storing any data on the device? In other words, they can connect to the network and read data but not store files on the iPad.

Also, we are considering implementing laptops for some users and have the same concerns with security as with iPads; these will be Windows 7 systems connecting via wired or wireless scenarios.

Your guidance is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many applications that provide the functionality that you are looking for.

They are called 'Kiosk Stations' and can limit user access to the screen, disk and even system buttons (using an enclosure).

Find much more information here : [www.ipadenclosures.com](http://www.ipadenclosures.com) - directed towards a full enclosure solution.
If you like to have just a lockdowned machine - you can restrict some features using iPhone Configuration Utility [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/FA_iPhone_Configuration_Utility/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Comment: Thanks, dalimama. Can the iPhone Config Utility be used on an iPad? Also, does it work for iOS 5 or only for 4? Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, iPhone config utility can be used with iPads too, and works under any iOS.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very interesting question for me as I am currently investigating the use of personal mobile devices for professional purposes.

Certainly, the global recession has seen many companies re-adjust their budgets, often at the cost of hardware. Similarly, the rise in smartphones, has seen more and more employees using their own devices in the office. 
Maybe this deserves it's own topic, but what is the general consensus on personal devices at work?

And another angle: many companies are blocking social network on the company computers, resulting in employees using personal devices to access them. (in many cases there is not a severe security risks, but there have been plenty of high-profile cases where social networking sites have gotten employees, and employers, into difficulty)

Is it wise to be passing on responsibility for content control onto a device that you have no responsibility for?
What happens when the employees leave the company, and take data with them?

Alex, I know you are trying to prevent them getting data files onto the device, which should stop large migrations of information, however, it wont prevent manual re-entry of information in smaller portions - in some businesses this is just as dangerous.

Comment: Hi @Louise, welcome to [security.se]! Please take a moment to review the [FAQ] - this is not a regular forum, as you are probably used to elsewhere: Answers should be reserved only for, well, actual answers to the question. If you register your user, you'll be able to gain reputation and leave comments (that are not answers), but this is still not really a discussion-like forum.... Though you are welcome to come by The DMZ ([chat])! :)